# Trying to resize image from mysql with PHP - multiple warnings with tested function?

Tags: php, mysql, image

Ok, I have been following [How to resize image without storing it on a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270233/how-to-resize-image-without-storing-it-on-a-folder) as they seem to have been able to take an image and resize it and output the image back out using PHP.

I have tried to implement their method but am not only not getting an image but multiple warnings as well. 
Right now I can output back the **image data** (I don't know the difference between image resource and image data) of the original image (so the original size) using this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sqlserver", 'username', 'password');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "SELECT image, image_type FROM imageblob WHERE user_id=".$id; //select most recent image where user id equals id in accounts using DESC and stores in $sql

/*** prepare the sql ***/
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
/*** exceute the query ***/
$stmt->execute(); 
/*** set the fetch mode to associative array ***/
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
/*** set the header for the image ***/
$array = $stmt->fetch();
 /*** check we have a single image and type ***/
 if((sizeof($array) == 2) && empty($array['image']) == false)
 {

     $imgdata = $array['image']; //store img src
     $src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$imgdata;
     //echo 'There are images';
 }
 else
 {
     //echo 'no images';
     $src = '../images/noimage3.png';

 }
        return $src;
    }
```

If I output an `<img>` with $src as the src, this works. 
I have taken the resize_image function from the above question and modified it like they said in their answer:

```
function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=FALSE) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file); //this is line 233
    $r = $width / $height;
    if ($crop) {
        if ($width > $height) {
            $width = abs(ceil($width-($width*abs($r-$w/$h))));
        } else {
            $height = abs(ceil($height-($height*abs($r-$w/$h))));
        }
        $newwidth = $w;
        $newheight = $h;
    } else {
        if ($w/$h > $r) {
            $newwidth = $h*$r;
            $newheight = $h;
        } else {
            $newheight = $w/$r;
            $newwidth = $w;
        }
    }
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file); //this is line 252
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height); //254

    ob_start();
imagejpeg( $dst, NULL, 100); // or imagepng( $dst, NULL, 0 );
$final_image = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

return $final_image;
}
```

Apparently this should output the image DATA, which I what I need to be able to echo it in an `<img>`.

Here is where I try to pass the image blob to the resize function and where things get complicated:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sqlserver", 'username', 'password');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "SELECT image, image_type FROM imageblob WHERE user_id=".$id; //select most recent image where user id equals id in accounts using DESC and stores in $sql

/*** prepare the sql ***/
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
/*** exceute the query ***/
$stmt->execute(); 
/*** set the fetch mode to associative array ***/
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
/*** set the header for the image ***/
$array = $stmt->fetch();
 /*** check we have a single image and type ***/
 if((sizeof($array) == 2) && empty($array['image']) == false)
 {

     $imgdata = $array['image']; //store img src

     $src = $this->resize_image($imgdata, 50, 50, FALSE); //should resize WITHOUT cropping image
     //echo 'There are images';
 }
 else
 {
     //echo 'no images';
     $src = '../images/noimage3.png';

 }
        return $src;


    } //end of chat image
```

And yet no image is output. I am getting several warnings that I cannot make sense of given that the function has worked for others:

[image]

Leads me to believe I am not passing the right file to the function. What am I doing wrong here? How can I just resize an image from my data base? I have looked at most other approaches and can't get this.

Comment: your `$file` value is not correct. Can you edit your question to show us which lines are the lines that are referenced in the error output?

Comment: image resource is a container for the data, a bit like an array contains values, it's a reference point for the whole object rather than just parts of it.

Comment: @Martin I have edited the code

Comment: All the references to `$file` expect a filesystem object but are instead being given a blob object, that's the cause of your issues. You might as well save the blob object in a temporary location on your disc drive and then reference it, before `unlink` ing it. That seems the easiest solution

Comment: where are your headers for displaying images?

Comment: @Martin is there any other way other than saving to disc drive? What is a filesystem object?

Comment: @Martin I think I have saved the blob to my disk drive how would I unlink it? Can you post some code?

Comment: `unlink($file);` will remove the file, as per http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: That isn't working. Is there any script that will just resize the image from blob data?

Comment: to be absolutely clear You need to `unlink` the absolute filepath to the file you created.